# Is there a mobile OS available that is non: google microsoft apple nokia blaclberry?

Tags: mobile, operating-system

I am looking for a safe privacy-protected alternative to google apple microsoft nokia blackberry OS's. Thank you.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_operating_system

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu touch. But there are only few phones that run it.